# App ID in android manifest.xml is different to app id in build.gradle

Tags: android, flutter

I'm currently using Flutter and I used a package to change the app id and name of the app some time ago. However, now the app-id in android manifest.xml is different from the one in build.gradle but everything is working fine, including firebase and I don't know why. Currently, the android manifest.xml contains the old app id while the build.gradle contains the new one. Will I face problems when I try to launch my app onto the Google play console or can I just ignore this?

Comment: you can put same app id that you have in build.gradle file to the manifest file as well. it may create issue while upload to playstore as while uploading they also check for manifest for permissions and other stuff.